# How to remove children from cloudformation constructs

Tags: aws-cdk

I am using `aws-cdk` for creating the stack of a new app. We have existing resources deployed with `Cloudformation`, such as route tables with our VPC peerings and other.

When i create a `Subnet` with `aws-cdk`, it automatically creates a route table.

However, i don't need this route table. I use another, already created route table. How can i remove the default routetable ?

I can i could use `CfnSubnet` instead of `Subnet`, but I was wondering if there is another solution.

```
Subnet Subnet = new Subnet(this, "Subnet", SubnetProps.builder()
            .withVpcId(vpc.getVpcId())
            .withAvailabilityZone("eu-west-1b")
            .withCidrBlock(String.format("10.%d.43.128/25", environmentId))
            .build());

CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation routeTableAssociation = (CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation) subnet.getNode().tryFindChild("RouteTableAssociation");

routeTableAssociation.setRouteTableId(Fn.importValue(String.format("%s-nat-nat000", environment)));

CfnRouteTable cfnRouteTable = (CfnRouteTable) subnet.getNode().tryFindChild("RouteTable");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you proposed is the best way to achieve that.